# How to make a block element adjust dynamically to the size of what is inside it?

Tags: html, css

If I have this code:

```css
li.name{
    border: 1px solid #A38870;
    background-color: #FA682D;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<li class="name">hi</li>
<li class="name">hello</li>
<li class="name">wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!</li>
```

The background extends all the way across the page.

How can I make the background adjust to the size of the text, without explicitly setting the width for each list element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 display: table;
```

add this css code in `li.name` css class.

Answer (score 2):

```
li.name{
  /* your suff */
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

This so when you float block elements they adapt to the content of the size, the problem is they float left, so they gonna be next to each other, to avoid this you can `clear: left` or `clear: both`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions, none really perfect; which one you want depends on your use case.

1. Use `display: table`.  This will work in new enough browsers but not in older IE versions.
2. Use `float: left; clear: both` as suggested above.  This will work as long as there are no other floats around, and break horribly otherwise.
3. Use browser-specific CSS (e.g. Gecko supports `width: -moz-fit-content`).  This has the obvious drawbacks.

For your case and today, `display: table` probably works best, but going forward we can hope that the `fit-content` value for `width` gets standardized.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use browser-specific CSS, writing a line for each browser like Justin Geeslin explained here :

[Is there a css cross-browser value for "width: -moz-fit-content;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839164/is-there-a-css-cross-browser-value-for-width-moz-fit-content)

```
p{
  width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
}
```

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox, but in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected, working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/3jRx7/1/

```
li.name{
    border: 1px solid #A38870;
    background-color: #FA682D;
    display:inline;
    list-style: none;
    line-height:36px;
    padding:4px;
}

li.name:after { 
    content:"\A";
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. OP needs the list to show one below the other as well

Comment: by adding the above property all the li elements will be shown in single line (for this example)

Answer (score 0):

try using `clear:both; float: left` properties.

Answer (score -2):

Give it `display: inline-block`

```
li.name{
    border: 1px solid #A38870;
    background-color: #FA682D;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 5px;

    display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: This won't work. OP needs the list to show one below the other as well