# Is there a CSS cross-browser alternative to Firefox' "width: -moz-fit-content;"?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I need some divs to **fit their content width** at the same time.

I am now doing it like this:

```
.mydiv {
    background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(1, 56, 110, 0.7);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0099FF;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
}
```

The last command *"width: -moz-fit-content;"* is **exactly** what I need!  The only problem is... it works only on Firefox.

I also tried with *"display:inline-block;"*, but I need these divs to behave like divs. Namely, every next div should be **under**, and not **inline**, the previous.

Do you know any possible cross-browser solution?

Comment: Chome supports `fit-content` now.

Comment: Every Browser (except IE) does now support `fit-content`. On every browser except Firefox, it works without the prefix, Firefox still needs `-moz-fit-content`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 192, accepted):

At last I fixed it simply using:

```
display: table;
```

Comment: I got here looking exactly for the same terms of your question. I did `display: table` and `margin: auto` to center a `form`. Great! :D

Comment: Along with, I had to use white-space:pre!important;

Comment: Doesn't respect some attributes, e.g. `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: Every Browser (except IE) does now support `fit-content`. On every browser except Firefox, it works without the prefix, Firefox still needs `-moz-fit-content`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 84):

Mozilla's MDN suggests something like the following [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)]:

```
 p {
  width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
}
```

Comment: can we specify width proerty twice as you did for styling p? like width: intrinsic;         /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content;  /* Firefox/Gecko */

Comment: `-moz-max-content` is only equivalent to `-moz-fit-content` while the parent element is wider.  `-moz-fit-content` will fit the content and wrap the text, but `-moz-max-content` will extend outside of the parent element. Same applies for Chrome's `-webkit-max-content` and `fit-content`.

Comment: Don't forget to add `width: max-content;`.

Answer (score 16):

In similar case I used: `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 11):

Is there a single declaration that fixes this for Webkit, Gecko, and Blink? No. However, there is a cross-browser solution by specifying multiple width property values that correspond to each layout engine's convention.

```
.mydiv {  
  ...
  width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
  ...
}
```

Adapted from: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Comment: This copies Justin Geeslin's answer from a year prior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839164/is-there-a-css-cross-browser-value-for-width-moz-fit-content/18032891#18032891

Answer (score 2):

I use these:

```
.right {display:table; margin:-18px 0 0 auto;}
.center {display:table; margin:-18px auto 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to prevent a long line of text from outgrowing past its container, and `max-width: fit-content` worked in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

I found a workaround: if the element is the last displayed subelement, setting `display: table-caption;` and `caption-side: bottom;` does have the same effect, together with `display: table;` on the parent object.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use some `br`s?

```
<div class="mydiv-centerer">
    <div class="mydiv">Some content</div><br />
    <div class="mydiv">More content than before</div><br />
    <div class="mydiv">Here is a lot of content that
                       I was not anticipating</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mydiv-centerer{
    text-align: center;
}

.mydiv{
    background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(1, 56, 110, 0.7);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0099FF;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YZV25/

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but it makes too difficult to handle top and bottom margin between the divs. I found a better solution simply using `display: table;` instead of `display: inline-block;`.