# What is the ie equivalent of -moz-fit-content and -moz-center

Tags: css

I am trying to center align link elements one below the other, inside a parent element where the elements take the minimum width and height like when using `display:inline-block`

```
.parent {
    text-align: -moz-center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    text-align: -ms-center;
}

.parent a {
    display:block;
    width:-moz-fit-content;
    width:-webkit-fit-content;
    width:-ms-fit-content;
    background-color:red;

}


<div class="parent">
  <a href ="#">Link1</a>
  <a href="#">Link2</a>
</div>
```

I see that it works for Chrome and Firefox but does not work for IE. Does anyone know what is the equivalent of  `-moz-center` and `-moz-fit-content` in IE ?

Comment: how about `text-align: center;` and `width: fit-content;` ?

Comment: text-align:center does not help in center aligning the links in this case. Also, width:fit-content shows an error in my IDE (Intellij Idea)

Comment: @balintpekker `text-align: center;` is not a replacement for `-moz-fit-content`

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839164/is-there-a-css-cross-browser-value-for-width-moz-fit-content) for -moz-fit-content and cross-browser

Answer (score 12):

Why not just use actual `inline-block` for the container? Also, `display:table` and `float:left` will have the same effect.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
}
.parent a {
  display: block;  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href ="#">Link1 is long</a>
  <a href="#">Link2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the job when I tested in jsbin, but for some reason, the display:inline-block makes the links align to the left in my code.

Comment: Check the style of the links in your code in the DOM inspector. Probably they get (by cascading) some styles with higher specificity that override `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the parent to display flex and center content:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add to this, that if you are trying to set the width of an inner region it can be best to use:

```
width: intrinsic;
```

This will use the width of the region you have rather than the whole area.

Answer (score -4):

it is not relevant to your topic but still i have a question??

why you want to use -moz-center and -moz-fit-content ???

you can render same result by another approach

SEE THIS FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/mk2zxujx/6/

for example

```
.parent{
margin:auto 0;
text-align:center;
}


.parent a {
display:block;
background-color:red;
color:white;    
}


a{
  width:auto;// to make it responsive - you can give your own value if you want
  min-width:50px; //since you asked for a minimum width 
}
```

i hope it will work in all the browsers

Comment: I was just trying to find something that works. The fiddle you shared does not have the minimum width for the links.

Comment: i have updated the fiddle,i have used this approach in many projects and it is clean.