# Alternative to width: max-content that supports max-width: 100%

Tags: css

I try to find a cross browser alternative to `width: max-content` since it is not supported by all browsers. Here is an example:

```css
div {
  width: intrinsic; /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content; /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum
<div>
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
Lorem ipsum
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
Lorem ipsum
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRBNVw

This does not work in IE 11 and Edge. As an alternative setting `display: table;` has been suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875637/1981832

This works fine except for respecting the `max-width: 100%`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQGRwK

So I am looking for another work around.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the browsers which support `max-width`: https://caniuse.com/?search=max-content

Since IE 11 doesn't, you can use `display: inline-block`, like this:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```